# Embedded Razor layout cannot be located

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I'm using Razor with emails templates in .NET core 3.

While I can get this all to works, I'd like to change my templates file (called EmailLayout.cshtml and located at /Pages/Shared/) as an Embedded resource.
Whenever I do that in VS, I got this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The layout view 'EmailLayout' could not be
>   located. The following locations were searched:
>   /Views/EmailLayout.cshtml /Views/Shared/EmailLayout.cshtml 
>   /Pages/Shared/EmailLayout.cshtml

Why my file couldn't be found?
What should I add to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer.

1) Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation nuget package

2) Add this to configuration in Startup :

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options => {
    options.FileProviders.Clear();
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(appDirectory));
});
```

3) Change the service to `services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `Build Action` of the file is set to `Content` in the `properties` of the View.
[image]

You could follow the steps to use `EmailLayout.cshtml`:

1.Create Layout View:
[image]

2.Be sure it is in `/Pages/Shared` folder:
[image]

3.EmailLayout should be like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>EmailLayout</h2>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

4.Add the following code to your Razor Pages or `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{    
    Layout = "EmailLayout";
}
```

Comment: Everything works fine when the build action is marked as "Content". What I want is to change the "Build Action" as Embedded Resource, but when I do that, it can't find my view anymore.